# Проблема кодировки PHP

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Добрый день. Есть одно слово ქართულად. в бд это слово в другой кодировке и выглядет так áƒ¥áƒáƒ áƒ—áƒ£áƒšáƒáƒ“ . Через php преобразую эти кракозябры в нормальный текст

вот код из PHP

```
$str = "áƒ¥áƒáƒ áƒ—áƒ£áƒšáƒáƒ“";

$cat_name = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", $str);

echo $cat_name;
```

Но почему-то это слово ქართულად отображается некоректно. Не могу понять как это исправить. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Я думаю корень зла кроется в неверной кодировки самой БД. Исправьте её на UTF-8. И всё должно будет сохраняться корректно.

Comment: это да. но в данный момент имеется уже огромная база, переделать ее не возможно. Остается преобразовывать средствами PHP

Comment: ох уж эти огромные базы, которые невозможно переделать

Comment: сейчас речь идет даже не о базе. у меня в переменной этот текст, который я хочу перевести на нормальный язык

Comment: А почему вы переводите его в кодировку cp1252 ? В этой кодировке https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 вообще нет символов того алфавита, в котором набрано то слово

Comment: проблема в том, что у вас не просто происходит перекодировка, а в том, что в базе теряется байт от символа, в итоге это совершенно другой символ, восстановить его теоретически можно побитовым сдвигом (никак не стандартной функцией), но нужно знать куда, чего и на сколько сдвигать - в общем для решения этой задачи нужно серьёзно изучить обе кодировки и ту в которой хранятся данные в БД и ту в которой эти данные поступают. Это нетривиальная задача, которая никак не решается стандартными функциями.

Comment: [ссылка](2cyr.com) узнал об этой кодировке через этот сайт

Comment: попробуйте на соединении с БД поставить ту кодировку, в которой текст изначально был занесен. потом прочитайте и посмотрите что получили